# How I can use Alamofire SDK for SSL link?

Tags: swift, alamofire

How I can use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) SDK for SSL link?

I need to connect to HTTPS URL how I can enable SSL certificate setting in Code using Alamofire in Swift 4.0.

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire by default will connect to a HTTPS URL.

Requests can be made with

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com")
    .response { response in 
        //Handle the response here
    }
```

Comment: it will give error : because SSL Setting is required .                                         error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem with Alamofire, but rather the service you're connecting to.